# Is there a way to change the color of part of a button in android studio?

Tags: xml, android-studio, kotlin

For example, from left to right, I want to change the color of a button to red, but only the first 10%, or 20%, etc.

Comment: You want to create a gradient?

Comment: Yes you can, u need to write custom drawable gradient xml.